# Putting Subversion Repositories in Subdirectories?

Tags: svn

If I have a /repos directory and inside I have X repositories setup and running, am I able to add /repos/TeamX/Project1, /repos/TeamX/Project2, etc where TeamX is a directory and not a subversion repository? If yes, how do I setup the permissions in my configuration file?

```
[TeamX/Project1:/]
@TeamX = rw
```

This is not working for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you're using SVNParentPath for the /repos directory, subversion will only find repositories in immediate subdirectories of /repos. /repos/TeamX/Project1 will **not** be discovered by SVN if your SVNParentPath is /repos. If you're using DAV and Apache, you need a separate Location stanza and SVNParentPath for each:

```
<Location /svn/TeamX/>
  Dav SVN
  SVNParentPath /repos/TeamX/
  ...
</Location>

<Location /svn/TeamY/>
  Dav SVN
  SVNParentPath /repos/TeamY/
  ...
</Location>
```

Each stanza would specify its own auth file specific to that repository. For instance, the TeamX auth file could look like:

```
[Project1:/]
@TeamX = rw

[Project2:/]
@TeamX = r
```

Comment: This is the solution I finally came up with as well and implemented. I just didn't like having 2 auth files. I have redundancies in groups this way which I do not love.